# couchbase client store returns false

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

I have installed couchbase 1.8 and using the couchbase .net client library.
Did all the configurations as given in the documentation as below, but the client.store always fail and returns false.

---

```
<configSections>
<section name="couchbase" type="Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase"/>
</configSections>
<couchbase>
<servers bucket="default" bucketPassword="">
<add uri="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8091/pools/default"/>
</servers>
</couchbase>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

---

```
CouchbaseClient client = new CouchbaseClient(); //this creates a not null client object
bool result = client.store(Storemode.Add,"test","Couchbase test"); // this returns false always
string str = client.Get("test") as string; // this returns null always
```

---

I'm able to do telnet to the 8091 port. 
telnet takes to a blank screen, typing any key comes out of telnet session saying client sent a bad request. I'm guessing this is the correct behaviour, but somehow store is failing. I dont see any activity on the couchbase default databucket.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks right.  But if you've previously saved a non-string value for the key "test", then your code will yield false for result and null for string.

StoreMode.Add will work once and only once for a Store operation for a given key.  So if you'd previously saved, say an int, for the key "test" then Store will fail.  And the as cast will also return null.

If you try StoreMode.Set, does the code run properly?

Comment: Even the Storemode.set fails. actually i was never able to insert anything into the DB no matter what key i give. i'm pretty sure the key doesnt exist. Also I dont see any activity on the couchbase web console for the default bucket. It seems the request is not even reaching the DB.

Comment: Hi John, I'm able to do telnet to the couchdb server on port 11211 from my remote machine and able to store and get through telnet. But from the .net client.get and store both fail. It tries to make a connection and then seems to be timing out. Is there anything that the client needs to have to access when I'm able to connect with telnet?

Comment: There shouldn't be any additional requirements.  You might want to try enabling logging, which is described under "Configuring Logging" at http://www.couchbase.com/develop/net/current.  Something else to try is to clone the Couchbase.AspNet sample at https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-aspnet and try running the sample MVC app.

Comment: You may also want to try client.ExecuteStore().  I found that this works with plain old strings, when Store() produced strange behavior (e.g., did not store).  As a test, you may also want to try storing a POCO class that is marked with the [serializable] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem.

After you install Couchbase Server, on the config website, on Server Nodes tab, you should see the IP of the server.

That IP can be a wrong one (because it is assigned randomly by the installer).

If it is the wrong one (not a public IP for example), follow [these steps](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-bestpractice-cloud-ip.html) to set up the right IP. Also make sure you have firewall either turned off either you have the [ports](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-network-ports.html) unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem can lead to this error is blocked by firewall in development environment.
You can resolve this by bypass couchbase ip server in IE: Tools/Internet Options/Connections/LAN Settings/Advanced/Exceptions.

Regards.